# Не могу обновить локальний репозиторий с помощью git pull

Tags: git, git-pull

Вчера работал в локальном репозитории на офисной машине. В конце рабочего дня запушил все коммиты на удаленный репозиторий. Проверил репо на GitHub - все изменения пришли.
Вечерком решил продолжить работу с дома. Склонировал данный репозиторий к себе на ноут и начал работать. В конце дня снова запушил все измененния на удаленный репо.
Сегодня на офисной машине хотел запулить все изменения в локальный репозиторий. Выполнил:

```
git pull
```

Увидел сообщение об ошибке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По совету Git выполнил:

```
git pull udigital master
```

Получил следующее сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал другой вариант:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=udigital/master master
```

Получил такое сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге в локальном репозитории файлы не обновились. Как добавить изменения из удаленного репозитория и продолжить работать на локалке?

Answer (score 2):

В моем случае помогли следующие команды:

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
git fetch
```

А вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998832/git-pull-fails-unable-to-resolve-reference-unable-to-update-local-ref) на ответ на англоязычном StackOverflow на котором этот вопрос был решен.